# linear gradient x proportion codenameone

Tags: codenameone

i am using linear gradient horizontal. I want to use more of the starting gradient color than ending one. Presently both color have equal proportion ie meet in the center. How can i get more of one color than the other? Also i came to know that setBackgroundGradientRelativeX etc method only applies to radial gradient not linear one. Moreover i have lots of various simple gradients in the designs, so i dont want to use images everywhere. It would be troublesome.

```
categoryTitle.setUIID("partyCategoryTitle");            
categoryTitle.getAllStyles().setBackgroundGradientStartColor(0x73a0ff);
categoryTitle.getAllStyles().setBgImage(null);
categoryTitle.getAllStyles().setBackgroundGradientEndColor(0xffffff);
categoryTitle.getAllStyles().setBackgroundGradientRelativeX(1);
categoryTitle.getAllStyles().setBackgroundGradientRelativeY(10);
categoryTitle.getAllStyles().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_GRADIENT_LINEAR_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

As gradients currently [don't really work on Android](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1696) I'd avoid it.

I can't stress enough how badly gradients perform in the current implementation when they do work. Adding features to something that isn't working properly at this time is not a priority.